# Change List<Pair<T,U>> to Map<T,U>

Tags: java, java-8

how can I replace List of Pair (List>) to Maps as long as the list has no duplicates.

Comment: With a loop? Have you at least tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the List and do the right thing with each element to pull it apart and build a Map from it:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> mylist;

Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Pair<String, Integer> aPair : mylist) {
    myMap.put(aPair.getLeft(), aPair.getRight());
}
```

Or generically, in a method:

```
public <T,U> Map<T, U> toMap(List<Pair<T, U>> aList) {
    Map<T, U> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Pair<T, U> aPair : aList) {
        myMap.put(aPair.getLeft(), aPair.getRight());
    }
    return myMap;
}
```